# What's the difference between kafka.javaapi.* and org.apache.kafka.*?

Tags: apache-kafka

I am a new learner of kafka. What made me confused is that there seems to be two packages of kafka clients.

One is **kafka.javaapi.*** like

```java
import kafka.javaapi.producer.Producer;
import kafka.producer.KeyedMessage;
import kafka.producer.ProducerConfig;
```

the other is **org.apache.kafka.***. like

```java
import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer<K,V>
```

which is shown in page http://kafka.apache.org/082/javadoc/index.html?org/apache/kafka/clients/producer

What's their differences?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Before Kafka 0.8.2, `kafka.javaapi.producer.Producer` was the only official Java client (producer) which is implemented with Scala.

From Kafka 0.8.2, there comes a new Java producer API, `org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer`, which is fully implemented with Java.

[Kafka 0.8.2 Documentation](http://kafka.apache.org/documentation.html#producerapi) says

> We are in the process of rewritting the JVM clients for Kafka. As of 0.8.2 Kafka includes a newly rewritten Java producer. The next release will include an equivalent Java consumer. These new clients are meant to supplant the existing Scala clients, but for compatability they will co-exist for some time. These clients are available in a seperate jar with minimal dependencies, while the old Scala clients remain packaged with the server.

If you are interested in `kafka.javaapi.producer.Producer`, refer to [2.1 Producer API](http://kafka.apache.org/081/documentation.html#producerapi) in Kafka 0.8.1 Documentation.

Comment: So, for new developments (even if Scala ones), `org.apache.kafka` API should be used?